# SQLAlchemy how to sets key attribute of hybrid_property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, hybrid

I'm using a hybrid_property to combine or manipulating column value.  And i want to get a 'key' attribute of this hybrid_property columns.  Here the code.

```
class Foo(Base):

    name = Column(String)
    address = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)

    @hybrid_property
    def full_address(self):

        return '{}, {}'.format(self.address, self.city)

    @full_address.expression
    def full_address(self):

        return func.str('{}, {}'.format(self.address, self.city))
```

and within Python Shell:

```
>>> fld = Foo.name
>>> fld.key
'name'
>>> fld = Foo.full_address
>>> fld.key
>>> type(fld.key)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

how to get fld.key is a 'full_address'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've got the answer

@hybrid_property
def full_address(self):
    if isinstance(self, Foo):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.address, self.city)
    else:
        return Column('full_address', String)